# Ошибка копирования docker-файла

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Ниже приведен мой докер файл:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["JWT_Draft/JWT_Draft.csproj", "JWT_Draft/"]
COPY ["JWAuthorisationPullCommon/JWAuthorisationPullCommon.csproj", "JWAuthorisationPullCommon/"]
RUN dotnet restore "JWT_Draft/JWT_Draft.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/JWT_Draft"
RUN dotnet build "JWT_Draft.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "JWT_Draft.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "JWT_Draft.dll"]
```

В PowerShell выполняю скрипт билда образа:

```
 PS C:\Docs\ProjectsIn\JWT App\JWT_Draft_Back\JWT_Draft> docker build -t trainingdickerrepo/jwtserver .
```

Получаю ошибку :

> Step 6/17 : COPY ["JWT_Draft/JWT_Draft.csproj", "JWT_Draft/"] COPY
> failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore:
> stat JWT_Draft\JWT_Draft.csproj: file does not exist

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу разобраться что валится

Comment: пробовали ли вы написать команду копирования согласно [документации](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) без использования квадратных скобок ?

Comment: Нет, Visual Studio при добавлении докер файла такой рисует

Comment: попробуйте запустить `docker build -t trainingdickerrepo/jwtserver -f JWT_Draft .` из папки `JWT_Draft_Back`.

Comment: Правильно валится, указанный файл в контексте докера отсутствует. `JWT_Draft` там лишняя, Dockerfile же в этой папке уже.

Comment: Если честно не совсем понял